# xmpp server in Azure

Tags: azure, xmpp, openfire

I have a need to host an XMPP server in the cloud, essentially for chat, but other possibilities in the future.

I have just a couple of questions:

1) I need to install the XMPP server via a command line script, and Openfire seems to be the weapon of choice these days, but I dont think it has the ability to install without user interaction (i.e. silent install). Can anyone recommend a good XMPP server to be installed silently?

2) In regards to Azure, Im am lead to believe that all communication TO Azure needs to be on port 80, but most XMPP clients/servers run on 5222. How can I make this work on both the client and the Azure server?

That should be enough to get started.

Thanks

Comment: No, not all communications to Azure has to be on port 80. Some clients run their network applications using port!=80 on Azure.

Comment: thanks ahmet, I cant seem to find any references to this, can you give me an example?

Comment: actually, I found some examples, dont worry about it

Comment: share with us (: I don't know either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I thought I would share what I have found so far:

You can specify an end point `port` and protocol (i.e. TCP) to connect to Azure on, so this might be ok.

here is an example blog post: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/01/17/Creating-an-external-facing-Azure-Worker-Role-endpoint.aspx

In theory I can get a worker role running on port 5222 (the default XMPP port) and run a XMPP server on that port.

But I have yet to try this out. I will keep you all posted.